# ${!name:=val} not setting $name?

Tags: bash

According to the bash manual, ! implies that the value of val1 should be used as parameter for the expansion. So why isn't val2 set to "text" after line 6?

```
echo ${val1:-"val1 not set"} # val1 not set
echo ${val1:="val2"} # val1=val2
echo ${val1+"val1 set"} #check that val1 is set
echo ${!val1:-"val 2 not set"} # val2 not set
echo ${!val1:="text"} #  val 2 should be set? 
echo ${!val1:-"val2 not set"} # val2 empty
echo ${val2:-"val2 not set"} # val2 empty
val2="val2 set"  # val2 set from here on
echo ${!val1:-"val2 not set"} 
echo ${val2:-"val2 not set"}
```

Comment: Seems like a bug to me, but I guess you'd have to get the opinion of the bash programmers.

Comment: I agree; I was surprised that the `!` forms worked with other operators at all, but `:=` does seem to be a even more surprising exception.

Comment: Note that there's generally no way to assign to variables indirectly, except by using `eval`. So they may have felt no need to allow default assignment like this.

Comment: Why do you need this? In general, indirect variables are a bad idea, and you should be able to use arrays for anything you might have needed them for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to be fixed in `bash` 4.4:

```
$ bash/bash tmp.bash
val1 not set
val2
val1 set
val 2 not set
text
text             <------ Line 6 now outputs text
text             <------ As does line 7
val2 set
val2 set
```

(`bash/` is my local working directory of the Git repository; it contains a local build of 4.4.)

Comment: Definitely broken in `GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin15)`

Comment: Right; I mentioned 4.4 because 4.3 still has the behavior mentioned by the OP. Good to know it isn't a regression introduced by 4.0 :)

Comment: I must have missed the 4.3 reference; I wish there was an easy way to update the darwin version... :/

Comment: It's fairly easy to install the latest version with [Homebrew](http://brew.sh). Anything requiring the version shipped with OS X is probably using it as `/bin/sh` and should only be using POSIX-compliant features anyway.

Comment: @chepner : variable expansions are generally discouraged for portability then?

Comment: I don't see this listed in the NEWS file in the bash-4.4-rc1 sources. That's unfortunate (assuming it was an intended change).

Comment: Thanks for confirming my suspicion.